# Gradle Build Running takes so long

Tags: android, linux, gradle

That's the android studio 3.1RC with gradle version 3.3 and android plugin version 2.2.3.

My problem is that android studio takes too long to build the gradle and gives me java io exception error.
By the way, I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq7qv.png)

Comment: VOILA!!!!it's solved

Comment: TNX for your help

Answer (score 0):

**For the exception:**
Go to *"YourSdkPath"*/build-tools/*"TheVersionYou'reUsing"*/ and then right click on ".aapt" file, properties -> permissions and check "Allow executing file as program".
Give the same permission for '.dx' and '.zipalign' files in the same directory if the above solution didn't work.

**For slow build:**
Enable gradle offline work, go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and then check "Offline Work" option.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to speed up your builds is to update your android gradle plugin to a newer version: 3.1.1 is much faster than 2.2.3 (especially in the incremental build).